# Jmeter - Json Extractor removing white space causes test to fail

Tags: jmeter, json

Apologies if this is something fundamental which I should already know. I've got a test set up in jmeter using a Json Extractor. The data which it is extracting is in the format:

```
"data item 1", "data item 2", "data item 3"
```

The problem I have is that the extractor is pulling the data out and removing the spaces.

Is this normal? Or is there a setting I need to tweak to stop it doing this?

The service under test is using a Swagger page as a front end and the output from the service is in the format I describe above.

I can alter my expected results to remove all the spaces, but this may cause issues further down the line.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual payload look like vs. the JSON path you're using?

Comment: Can't actually show you the payload as it's on a different system which I can't transfer stuff out of. As it is, having done some playing about, I think this is Swagger being 'helpful' and formatting stuff to make it more readable.

Comment: I'm really confused . . . you're running Jmeter directly against the API and trying to generate known good data using swagger which you're then codifying into Jmeter?

Comment: Not quite ernie. I'm producing the Jmeter tests based on a set of manual tests which were executed in Swagger. We know the system is good and acting correctly, we just need the jmeter tests to work. Happily now, they do! :)

Comment: The answer on SO says no spaces were removed. It's unclear to me what your actual fix was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in the main Stack Overflow space and got a good answer back from someone there:

[jmeter-json-extractor-removing-white-space-causes-test-to-fail - Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369834/jmeter-json-extractor-removing-white-space-causes-test-to-fail)